# Decompiling using apktool giving error

Tags: android, apk

while decompiling an apk using apktool it gives me [image: UPDATED IMAGE]
It's not the first time I got such error, there are some apks which give me this error.
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Do you have latest version of the apktool?

Comment: Downloaded the new version but get new error.. check the question , updated the image

Answer (score 2):

Read over this: https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/FrameworkFiles

You are missing frameworks for whatever rom/place/thing that APK came from.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you need a file framework from that apk file, that file framework place in **/system/framework/** , if on the path having some apk file, you can try use it

after that, try to decompile again using this step

> D:\apktool>apktool if framework-res.apk
>   I: Framework installed to: C:\Users\Aduh\apktool\framework\1.apk

and than

> D:\apktool>apktool d yourapk.apk

I hope my answer can help you....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Click <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Then enter apktool
3. Delete all files
4. Now you can use `apktool d appilcation_name.apk`

Comment: Not working at all, give a different solution if possible.